# How to test whether message appears in long log?

Tags: python, unit-testing, logging

I have a method that logs many warnings and infos. I want to test whether it produces a particular message (so for the particular test it doesn't matter if any other messages are produced).

Currently I use the following code which I want to unit-test:

```
import logging

def my_method():
    do_something()  # may also produce logging messages
    logger.info('Finished doing something.')  # the message I want to unit-test
```

And this is the test code:

```
import unittest
from testfixtures import log_capture

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):

    @log_capture()
    def test_do_something(self, log_checker):
        my_method()
        log_checker.check(('root', 'INFO', 'Finished doing something.'))
```

The test fails because `my_method()` also produces a log message:
    AssertionError: sequence not as expected:

```
same:
()

first:
(('root',
  'INFO',
  'Finished doing something.'),)

second:
(('root',
  'INFO',
  'Busy doing something inside my_method.'),
 ('root',
  'INFO',
  'Finished doing something.'))
```